# How to define defauletProps in propTypes using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-proptypes

I have a component named ( createComponents ) with the following properties : values,  type  and success .
And I want to define ( propTypes )  for my component .

```
const createComponents=(props)=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <Error ve={props.values} type={props.type} success={props.success}/> 
            <span>{Math.floor(Math.random()*30)}</span>
            <br/>
            <span>Welcome to React World Developer</span> 
            <br/>
            <Error>
               <span className="error2" onClick={()=>alert('HI')}>Error not foound!</span>
               <br/>
               <span className="error" onClick={()=>alert('HI Tessa')}>Error not foound!</span> 
               <br/>
               <span className="error" onClick={props.handler}>Spesial Error!</span> 
            </Error> 
        </div>
    )
}

createComponents.propTypes={
    values:  PropTypes.string, 
    type: PropTypes.string,
    success: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    handler: PropTypes.func,
    values: PropTypes.defauletProps 
}
```

and in APP.js
`<CreateComponents values='W3Schoolss' type='Programming' success={100} handler={()=>handler('Sara')} />`

Now, I want the `values` to be defauletProps. so I delete ( values='W3Schoolss') in `<CreateComponents values='W3Schoolss' type='Programming' success={100} handler={()=>handler('Sara')} />`
Thank you to everyone who helps me

Answer (score 0):

You can define defaultProperty with `ComponentName.defaultProps`

```
ComponentName.defaultProps = {
  name: 'SomeDefaultName'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultProps` property like:

```
createComponents.defaultProps = {
   values = 'defaultValue' 
   types = 'defaultType'
   sucess = 'defaultSuccess'
}
```